# How do I use OR condition under 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' in 'Conditional formatting' in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, I am trying to create one conditional formatting rule where a cell is highlighted, when the cell contains either

```
TODO,
TBD,
..
```

I have tried creating a rule of type

```
'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'
```

and under 
    'Format values where this formula is true', 
I used:

```
=OR((SEARCH("TODO", A1)>0),(SEARCH("TBD", A1)>0))
```

[image: excel screenshot]
(For some reason, excel is changing cell reference A1 to XER1 automatically)

However, the rule is not having an effect.

However, if I use this condition:

```
=SEARCH("TODO", A1)>0
```

the conditional formatting works.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Excel 2007 on windows 7 64-bit.

Thank you.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980763/conditional-formatting-with-or-function

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do after selecting the column of your values, is Conditional Formatting, Highlight cell Rules, More and choose use a formula under Format value where this formula is true write  =OR(A1="todo",A1="tbd") and choose your format then ok 
To respond at your request write this formula
=OR(IFERROR(FIND("todo",A1,1),0)>0,IFERROR(FIND("tbd",A1,1),0)>0) I think in yours when it is not found it gives error

Comment: Thanks @Sam. The cell value can be some thing like "xyz todo abc" i.e. the cell value may not exactly be "todo". Your formula may not work then.

Comment: In that case create a new column D for your formula you will have true or false and with conditional formatting D1=true highlight the cells

Comment: =OR(IFERROR(FIND("todo",A1,1),0)>0,IFERROR(FIND("tbd",A1,1),0)>0)   use this formula for contains

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for me.

Comment: This formula worked for me: =OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("TODO", A1)>0,0),IFERROR(SEARCH("TBD", A1)>0,0))